# Where should twitter embed javascript go in a ctools plugin

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, social-network

I have a ctools plugin with the twitter embed javasacript in there, but where should the javascript go? Should it be in the template file, or should be be outputted into the block in the plugin file?

Comment: I might no understand the question, but why don't you stick it into a regular .js file and [drupal_add_js](api.drupal.org/drupal_add_js) it?

Comment: It is twitter embed code, javascript embedded in the page, and appears to need to be embedded in the page to work.

Comment: Put it in a block Andrew.

Comment: But I am already using a ctools plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing "special" either about "Twitter embed" or "javascript and plugins".

The solution is the same as for other javascript includes, put the javascript in `[module]/js/file_name.js`, and call [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/drupal_add_js) on it.

Comment: it is similar to this code: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6933

Comment: I hear you, but like I said in my answer, it doesn't matter where the code comes from, or what it looks like. My approach is generally applicable to most situations where you want to include javascript. (The single large exception I can think of is when a form [#attached](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) is more appropriate.

Comment: I would still have to call that script in the page, unless I can assign it to an ID of a div or something...